# Change the height of the Firefox URL bar using CSS

Tags: firefox

I have increased the height of the URL bar (Firefox 47) with

```
#urlbar {min-height: 50px !important;}
```

This makes the bar bigger, but now the bottom of it cuts off.  That is, I can still only see the top 25 pixels, even though there's room in the Nav Bar for a 50-px URL bar.

What do I need to change to see the full URL bar?